# docker healthcheck shows not found in django

Tags: python, django, docker, wget

I added health check to my Dockerfile:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=1m --timeout=5s --retries=2 --start-period=10s \
  CMD wget -qO- http://localhost:8070/healthcheck || exit 1
```

In my project main urls.py file I added entry:

```
url(r'^healthcheck/', lambda r: HttpResponse())
```

The project is activated and deployed, so I can understand the healthcheck is valid, however - I keep getting:

> 2017-12-17 13:25:27,891 WARNING base 51 140551932685128 Not Found:
>   /healthcheck

written to the logs (once a minute).
The log entry is added also when I run the wget from inside the server.

Is it an issue with the healthcheck syntax, the django entry set up or the wget in docker?

Please assist. Thanks.

Comment: Does the container have a healtheck field, when you inspect the container ?
`docker inspect <id> --format "{{.Config.Healthcheck}}"`

I tried the `HEALTCHECK` line and got after building:

`Unknown type "\\" in HEALTHCHECK (try CMD)`

After removing the backslash between `start-period` and `CMD` it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the healthcheck url:
http://localhost:8070/healthcheck

should be:
http://localhost:8070/healthcheck/

because the trailing slashes setting in django.

Comment: is there a hack to  make it without slash as some loadbalancers redirects if slash is present at end

Comment: @MohitAngiras - remove/modify the  trailing slashes setting